# ideviceinstaller -i returns Segmentation fault: 11

Tags: ios, debugging, react-native, visual-studio-code

I'm using vscode to write react native app and want to debug it on iOS device. So i installed the ideviceinstaller using "brew install ideviceinstaller" and changed the target to "device" in lanuch.json. But the following error occured:

```
[Error] "Could not debug. Error while executing command 'ideviceinstaller -i /Users/leon/Desktop/AwesomApp/ios/build/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/AwesomApp.app': Error while executing command 'ideviceinstaller -i /Users/leon/Desktop/AwesomApp/ios/build/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/AwesomApp.app'"
```

then I run

```
ideviceinstaller -i /Users/leon/Desktop/AwesomApp/ios/build/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/AwesomApp.app
```

in the console and get the following output:

```
Uploading AwesomApp.app package contents... DONE.
Installing '(null)'
- CreatingStagingDirectory (5%)
- ExtractingPackage (15%)
- InspectingPackage (20%)
- TakingInstallLock (20%)
- PreflightingApplication (30%)
- InstallingEmbeddedProfile (30%)
- VerifyingApplication (40%)
- CreatingContainer (50%)
- InstallingApplication (60%)
- PostflightingApplication (70%)
- SandboxingApplication (80%)
- GeneratingApplicationMap (90%)
Segmentation fault: 11
```

I google it, and some other guys meet the same issue, and they solved it by reinstalling the lasted homebrew and then reinstalling the ideviceinstaller. But it does't work for me.
So, anyone can help?